# Oracle RIGHT OUTER JOIN not working properly?

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

Ok, so lets say I have two tables: Table1[Rows: id, num, name], Table2[Rows: num, description]. I would like to query Table1 to result the id's for all rows on which Table1.num = Table2.num. So I writte:

```
SLECT t1.id, t1.num, t2.description
 FROM Table1 t1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
      Table2 t2 ON (t1.num = t2.num)
```

/*Table2 has only one record which is as follows: Num = 123, Description = 'Abc'*/

So my result should be something like this:
1, 123, Abc
2, 123, Abc
5, 123, Abc

But the result I'm getting is;
3, 111, Null
4, 222, Null

Comment: If you only want to match records that have the same `num` in both tables, why are you doing any kind of "outer" join (regardless of left vs. right, about you may also be confused)? What do you need to return? The right outer join will return one row for every row in table2 that does NOT have a matching `num` in table1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all rows in `a` along with matching rows in `b`, then use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
  SELECT count(a.object_id)
  FROM table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table2 b
       ON a.num = b.num /*I only have one record in table b, which num field = '123'*/
```

The `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the *first* table, regardless of whether the `ON` clause evaluates to true.  The `RIGHT JOIN` keeps all rows in the *second* table, regardless of whether the `ON` clause evaluates to true.  You seem to want a `LEFT JOIN`.

As a general rule, I do not use `RIGHT JOIN`.  I find it much easier to read `FROM` clauses with the logic "Keep all the rows in the tables I've seen so far".

Answer (score 0):

With `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, there will be *at least* as many rows as there are rows in the *right* table.

Comment: I only want the matching num on table1 from table2. So for example, let's say that in table1 I have 100 records, then I wan to Right Outer Join table2 using the num field. In table2 I only have one record which name field = 123. So In my result I want all records from table1 that match num 123

Comment: You'll probably need to add some sample data for both tables in your question along with expected and actual result of the query. I'm afraid I don't understand from just the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a join, you get the number of records from both tables that meet the criteria. If table A only has one record then table B likely has more than one record that meets the join criteria.

So it is unreasonable to expect only one record as a result. If you should, by business rules, have only one record then you need to filter the records in the second table so that only one will result. Which one you pick to return would entirely be dependant on the business rules and is a matter of data meaning not syntax.

Comment: So, what your saying is that even if I specify at the Right Outer Join to bring only records from Table1 that match num 123 (FROM table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.num = 123), the query will still return all records?

Comment: It will return all record that have num=123 in both tables.  So if table a has one record with  num=123 and table b has three records with  num=123 then three records will be returned because there are three records that meet the join conditions. This is true with a left join or an inner join or a right join.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for you response, but It seem's I didn't explained myself well. In my case, the query is returning all sorts of values that are not 123 in the num field, which are not suppose so to show because they don't met the clause.

Comment: Can you post some example data and the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

A SELECT DISTINCT resolved my issue. Thanks to all of you for your help!